# How to disable conditional formatting for "empty" cells in sheets when the empty cell contains a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have column A in which I enter a number and column B which calculates a new number based upon my entry in A if it is 12 characters long. Cool.

To visualize if I entered a number twice, I have:

1. conditional formatting to color the cell with the duplicate number red

Format cell background color red, if

`=COUNTIFS($B:$B; $B1)>1`

2. a formula in C which shows the word DUPLICATE in the cell of the row the duplicate is present

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B; B4)>1; "DUPLICATE"; )`

The problem is that the conditional formatting as well as the formula in C assumes "empty" cells in B as duplicates and colors them red and puts the word DUPLICATE as soon as I put the formula in a cell in B. It works when there is no formula in a cell in B.
How do I prevent this?

This is an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nq1jTKQiQEAf7ZrT1tHRGlVZt1G79gQuzoCjnmX_zM/edit?usp=sharing

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| NumberX  |NumberX+x |          |
| empty cell | empty cell containing formula | DUPLICATE |
| NumberY | NumberY+x | DUPLICATE |
| NumberZ | NumberZ+x |           |
| NumberY | NumberY+x | DUPLICATE |
| empty cell | empty cell containing formula | DUPLICATE |
```

I tried to reformat the syntax of the conditional formatting as well as the formula in column C, but can't seem to get it correctly.
I tried to add:

`=COUNTIFS($B:$B; $B1)*($B1<>"")`

to the conditional formatting, and it refrains from coloring emtpy cells red, but colors cells with content red.
I feel I am very close to understanding my error, but can't overcome the last inch.

Comment: the shared sheet has *restricted* access

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I was (and am, to be honest) struggling with formatting my post correctly. The UI lets me know I formatted some code improperly and I can't submit my edits and can't find out why. This was so frustrating that I overlooked checking my link and the permissions on it. It should be fixed now. My apologies again.
Edit: It seems to be my table. It doesn't render correctly and I have to put it into code brackets so I can click submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining your first working and last working formulas I'd suggest this change in your conditional formatting:

```
=(COUNTIFS($B:$B; $B1)>1)*($B1<>"")
```

In order to consider it true only when it appears more than once and it's not empty

Comment: This actually solved both of my issues. It removed the red label when the cell is empty AND I put it into my formula for cells as well!  
Initially I had this:  
`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B; B3)>1; "DUPLICATE"; )`  
  
to check for duplicates and it would put the word DUPLICATE also for empty cells, but I didn't want it to count empty cells as duplicates, so with your help, I tweaked the code to:  
`=IF((COUNTIF(B:B; B1)>1)*(B1<>""); "DUPLICATE"; )`  
and it works. The document now doesn't count (and mark) empty cells as duplicates. Much appreciated!